# How to remove / before index?

Tags: .htaccess

How can I remove the `/` before `index.(php|html ...)`?

Examples:

```
www.HTTP_HOST.com/x/index.php to www.HTTP_HOST.com/x

www.HTTP_HOST.com/../../../index.php to www.HTTP_HOST.com/../../..
```

I use this rewrite condition but the `/` remains.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html|hml)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|hml)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for removing the "/index.php" part:

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/ RewriteRule        
    ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,NS,L]
```

Redirect 301 means Moved Permanently so most search engines will remove index.php from URL.

Just remember to check if your mod_rewrite is enabled on your server. Usually mod_rewrite is enabled on Linux servers but not windows,

You can check this by looking in phpinfo().

Swift

Comment: This didn't work. It remove the index.php like my rewrite condition but the slash before index.php remains. www.HTTP_HOST.com/test/index.php -> www.HTTP_HOST/test/